# knitr: how to set keepaspectratio in figure

Tags: r, knitr

I have some figures generated by R too tall to fit on the page. I want to include these figures but scale down the figure according to a height restriction.

```
<<fig=TRUE,out.height='0.7\\textheight'>>=
```

Unfortunately, this squishes the plot vertically.

Inspecting the generated latex code reveals that the problem lies with the fact that `width=\maxwidth` is set automatically:

```
\begin{knitrout}\footnotesize
...
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth,height=0.7\textheight]{figures/view_unnamed-chunk-10} 
\end{knitrout}
```

How can I keep the `width=\maxwidth` specification from appearing in the `\includegraphics` statement without setting the `out.width` argument in `<<>>=` explicitly? In this example, `fig.width==fig.height` so I could additionally set `out.width='0.7\\textheight'` (and adjust accordingly for the any aspect ratio), but I would like know for the more general case.

Passing `keepaspectratio=TRUE` in `<<>>=` is ignored, so that doesn't seem to  be an option.

Comment: I can't remember where I saw it, but I found out that it's better to set `fig.show = "hide"` and then use `\includegraphics` later with the path to the figure being `figures/chunk-name-1`, where you replace `chunk-name` with the name of the chunk and `1` with the number of the plot you want to plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I found out that you can use the `out.extra` parameter to provide `keepaspectratio` option.

This is how it may look like:

```
<<out.height='0.7\\textheight',out.extra='keepaspectratio'>>=
```

The LaTex code then will look something like this:

```
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth,height=0.7\textheight,keepaspectratio]{figure/unnamed-chunk-1-1}
```